# conda source deactivate : bash: deactivate: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

I installed Conda at a different location than the default location on Ubuntu 16.4 using the official installation helper.

Now `conda create` and `source activate` works, but `source deactivate` gives me the error:

```
(deep) yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ source deactivate
bash: deactivate: No such file or directory
```

I checked this issue on Github: [#458: "Using `source deactivate` on a conda env fails unless the root anaconda directory is in PATH"](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/458). It seems to be related, but I do not understand what happens when I run `source deactivate` inside a conda environment. Is it because something is wrong with my PATH variables?

Here is the part of my `/.bashrc` related to Conda, if helpful.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/media/yuqiong/DATA/Anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/media/yuqiong/DATA/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/media/yuqiong/DATA/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/media/yuqiong/DATA/Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

### conda shortcuts
function actv() {
    #do things with parameters like $1 such as
    source activate "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I still have not figured out why `source deactivate` does not work anymore, but the good thing is `conda deactivate` works. I'm sticking with that now.

And I think the problem is I do not understand how conda works... Here is a gentle intro to package manager if anyone's interested...https://medium.com/@sdboyer/so-you-want-to-write-a-package-manager-4ae9c17d9527

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
conda deactivate
```

To deactivate or to go to the base source and then you can use

```
conda info --envs
```

to get the list of available sources

```
source activate <source_name>
```

and to activate a particular source.

Refer this for more -> [Managing environments - conda.io](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=environment#managing-environments)

Answer (score 3):

Just Put

```
conda deactivate
```

good to know

conda activate and conda deactivate only work on conda 4.6 and later versions